# Collection View returns nil when called in function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

I want to run a function which involves adding a sublayer to a collection view. However when I run the function the app crashes saying `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` When I print the collection view it shows up in the log as `none` so I know the collection view is the problem. The view has already been loaded when I call the function and I can see all of it's cells. The function is being called from another class, which I think might have something to do with the problem.

Here is the function that I am calling...

```
func displayCircle() {
         let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
        print(shapeLayer)


        print(collectionView)
        collectionView!.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }
```

Here is how I am calling this function from another class...

```
ViewController().displayCircle()
```

**EDIT:** This is my storyboard layout...

[image]

What could the problem be?

As you can see, I am using a page view controller. Hope this helps

Comment: You would have to find the collectionView inside its own view controller instance: `myViewController.collectionView` - Finding the view controller depends on the viewController structure of your app.

Comment: So, the problem is the way that I am calling the function? @Chris

Comment: So if the collection view is in the same view controller as this method, the collection view code is not the problem. You’ll need to get a reference to this view controller from the one calling the method. How is this view controller presented? Can you send a screenshot of storyboard?

Comment: You see using `ViewController()` makes a brand new plain and simple view controller instance in code, which of course does not have a `displayCircle()` method or a collection view, which is why it finds nil. To find a reference to the other view controller, you need to navigate the stack of presented view controllers. How to do this depends on whether you are using a tab bar controller, navigation controller, split view controller etc, which is why we cannot give a simple answer for this bit.

Comment: For example, if you are using a navigation controller, and both of these view controllers are presented on it, you would get a reference to the other view controller with something like: `let otherViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[index] as? OtherViewControllerClass` where `self` refers to the current view controller.

Comment: See my edits @Chris

Comment: Thanks @coder - so you’re using a `UIPageViewController` - I will edit my answer.

Comment: Just edited answer with some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collectionView is part of this same viewController, use self:

```
self.collectionView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

If the collectionView is in a different viewController, as it seems to be, you would need to get a reference to that view controller. How you do this depends on the structure of your app. You mention using a `UIPageViewController` and presumably both the view controllers are presented on it.

From one view controller, you can refer to another like this:

```
let pvc = self.parent as? UIPageViewController // Or your custom class
let targetViewController = pvc.viewControllers[index] as? YourTargetViewControllerClass
```

You might need to figure out what `index` you need. An alternative is to make sure each child view controller of the `UIPageViewController` has its own subclass, then find the one you want like this:

```
let pvc = self.parent as? UIPageViewController
let viewControllers = pvc.viewControllers.filter { $0 is CustomSubclass }
if let viewController = viewControllers.first as? CustomSubclass {
    viewController.displayCircle()
}
```

As the other answer states, using `ViewController()` creates a brand new view controller instance, not the one that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

There's likely a few issues here.

If you wanted to say `ViewController.displayCircle()` then `displayCircle` would need to be a static function. But I don't think that was your intention, you probably don't want to do that in this case, and also your static function syntax is wrong (`ViewController().displayCircle()` is wrong). But moving on... :)

`ViewController().displayCircle()` isn't how you properly reference the collectionView. First you need a reference to the other view controller. Then inside `displayCircle` you need to grab a reference to the `collectionView` if it's in another View Controller. So that would be `otherViewController.collectionView` provided the `collectionView` is public of course, and provided you have a reference to that other view controller somehow. Note that you can't just make a new reference of the other view controller, otherwise you'll be adjusting the layer on the new instance, not the original.

Last but not least, you're force unwrapping the `collectionView` - don't do that. Your app will crash if it's ever nil. Instead, take advantage of Swift's paradigms:

```
if let collView = collectionView {
     collView.layer...// etc
}
```

This last bit isn't the issue, but just good practice.

Comment: The function is called from another class. The class that has the function also contains the collection view. Just to clarify is there something wrong with the function itself or is it that I am creating a new instance. @JaredH

Comment: You're likely creating a new instance. In the ViewController that contains the `displayCircle` method, you need to grab a reference to the other, original collectionView instance, in the _other_ view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
ViewController()
```

creates a new instance other than the presented one ,when you reference the collectionView from it it's actually nil as you have to load the VC either from storyboard / xib ,  so you have to use delegate to reference the current VC that contains the collectionView

Comment: Since I am just a beginner so far, can you expand on how I would use a delegate to reference another ViewController and then call a function from it. @Sh_Khan